# Pad column with n zeros and trim excess values

Tags: awk, sed

For example, the original data file

`file.org` :

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  0
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Insert three data points (0) in column 2,
The output file should look like this

`file.out` :

```
1  0  3  4  5
6  0  8  9  0
11 0  13 14 15
16 2 18 19 20
21 7 23 24 25
```

Please help.

Comment: Very good edit! (+1) for that. I would still suggest changing the title a bit. Maybe something like _Pad column with n zeros and trim excess values_.

Comment: Good choice for the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{x=$2; $2=a[NR%n]+0; a[NR%n]=x} 1' file
1 0 3 4 5
6 0 8 9 0
11 0 13 14 15
16 2 18 19 20
21 7 23 24 25
```

Comment: I had the same idea in mind. This is a bit safer on the memory side!

Comment: @kvantour yeah, I like the simplicity of yours but he did say his input file is huge so I went with this (plus it's the first thing that sprang to mind :-) ).

Answer (score 3):

The following `awk` will do the trick:

```
awk -v n=3 '{a[NR]=$2; $2=a[NR-n]+0}1' file
```

Comment: @Bossjara This is not really what your original question is about, but you can just remove the `END` block to achieve this. (`awk -v n=5 '{a[NR]=$2; $2=a[NR-n]+0; print}' file`)

Comment: @Bossjara A part of Stack OVerflow is, next to asking and answering questions, also moderation and cleaning up. As you notice most of our comments below my answer are now irrelevant and confusing to future readers. Please be so kind as to remove all irrelevant comments from this entry.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since OP has edited question so adding solution as per new question.

```
awk -v count=3 '++val<=count{a[val]=$2;$2=0} val>count{if(++re_count<=count){$2=a[re_count]}} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 0 3 4 5
6 0 8 9 0
11 0 13 14 15
16 2 18 19 20
21 7 23 24 25
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v count=5 '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
$2{
  val=(val?val ORS OFS:OFS)$2
  $2=0
  occ++
  $1=$1
}
1
END{
  while(++occ<=count){
     print OFS 0
  }
  print val
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1   0   3   4   5
6   0   8   9   0
11  0   13  14  15
    0
    0
    2
    7
    12
```

Comment: I am really sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @Bossjara, Could you please check my EDIT answer and let me know then?

Comment: I cannot get it run.

Comment: Why, it worked fine for me.  Could you please do let me know if you getting any errors etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try Perl,

```
$ cat file.orig
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  0
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25

$ perl -lane ' BEGIN { push(@t,0,0,0) } push(@t,$F[1]);$F[1]=shift @t; print join(" ",@F) ' file.orig
1 0 3 4 5
6 0 8 9 0
11 0 13 14 15
16 2 18 19 20
21 7 23 24 25

$
```

Comment: I cannot use Perl, sorry.